# How to run automated tests on a desktop application via Jenkins?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, windows-application-driver

Sorry for my english, not my first language.

I work with automated testing. We made automated tests on a desktop application using Windows App Driver, C# and Selenium. The tests run fine when launched via Visual Studio, but I cant get the application to run on Jenkins.

I've tried the following commands on the `Execute Windows batch command` section on Jenkins:

```
cd C:\<projectFolder>
dotnet build
dotnet test
```

This works fine on windows terminal, but on Jenkins I can see in the console that it does build and start the tests, but the main application dont open. The process of the app appears on task manager, but it doesnt really start.

Any advice?

Comment: Are you getting an errors? Are you able to check the Windows Event Viewer? Can you clarify what you mean by "but it doesn't really start"?

Comment: On Jenkins console I get the error:

`OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Failed to locate opened application window with appId: C:\USE\USE.exe, and processId: 10712`

What I mean by "but it doesn't really start" is that the application process appears on windows task manager, but it does not open... like no splash screen, no login screen... so the automation has nothing to interact with.

Comment: Hm. I'm afraid there is no straight forward solution. I searched for the exception message and came across this GitHub issue: [Failed to locate opened application window with appId on Remote Desktop](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/1748). There are a bunch of things to try. The thing mentioned multiple times is waiting longer for the application to launch: `driver.AddAdditionalCapability("ms:waitForAppLaunch", "25")` where you can play with the amount of wait time. Others suggested looking into permission issues with whichever user is running the build in Jenkins.

Comment: Hi Greg, sorry for the delay in getting back to you. I managed to make it work by changing the way Jenkins runs. It was running as a service, when I launched it with the command `java -jar jenkins.war` it worked just fine. Thanks for answering!